# why in php websites has malware issue Continuously in javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, web, malware

Website is continuously getting the unwanted code of malware in js files. I have removed it but after sometime, it comes back.Than browser detects malware in website.

Answer (score 2):

yes i have resolved this kind of issue earlier

Do one thing install gotmls(Anti-Malware Security and Brute-Force Firewall - WordPress) wordpress plugin in your wordpress site 1) update the key after registration 2) scan the whole site 3) after this install wp-security plugin to make site more protected

Hope you will get your solution Cheers :)

one thing more if you find any affected file just click on the button automatically repair on this plugin

Comment: But what about the corephp and other pfp framework. In php website also malware affected.So what is do for that??

Comment: for this you have to do these steps first :
1) Scan you site with online scanner like https://sitecheck.sucuri.net// or google safe browsing first.
2) you will find the infected files, now after removal of code change the username and password of the site

Comment: I have try this all things but after some days it again malware infected.

Comment: which framework you are using please let me know? kindly set your site locally and do the same steps once

Comment: you can do one thing first clear all js file and change the permission to 0444